# Is the continuous extension of a diffeomorphism on an open, bounded set a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a diffeomorphism from an open, bounded set $X$ to an open, bounded set $Y$. Then, $f$ as well as $f^{-1}$ can be extended continuously to the closure $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$, respectively. Is there a standard argument that tells me that $\bar f: \bar X \rightarrow \bar Y$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Why do you expect that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ can be extended continuously?

Comment: The sets $X$ and $Y$ are open in what? $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: The continuous extensions may or may not exist. Are you assuming that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ have continuous extensions? Then indeed, these extensions will be inverses to each other (just by continuity).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. I have a specific problem where I know that both f and its inverse can be extended continuously. And yes, $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ are compact which should furhter simplify matters, right? I was thinking that this simply follows by continuity but I was not sure wether I had overseen some additional assumptions that are necessary such that $\bar f^{-1} \circ \bar f = Id$.